# JavaScript - Cant get data out of onload function (http request)

Tags: javascript, api, http, request, onload

so Im currently working on a programm which is working with an api.

I have two functions atm:

getBotID()

```
function getBotID(domain) {
  var url = "http://" + domain + ":8087/api/v1/botId";
  idRequest.open("GET", url);
  idRequest.onload = function() {
      var botID = JSON.parse(idRequest.responseText);
  };
  idRequest.send();
}
```

and getAuth()

```
function getAuth(domain, user, pass) {
  getBotID(domain);

  var url = "http://" + domain + ":8087/api/v1/bot/login";
  body = '{"username": ' + user + ', "password": ' + pass + ', "botId": ' + botID + '}';
  authRequest.open("POST", url);
  authRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  authRequest.onload = function() {
      var authToken = JSON.parse(authRequest.responseText);
  };
  authRequest.send(JSON.stringify(body));
}
```

I have to get the botID before I can try to get a new AuthToken so I call the getBotID() instantly in the getAuth() function.

**My problem is:** I cant get the botID outside of the onload() function of the http request in getBotID() because it will run like this:

1. start getAuth()
2. start getBotID()
3. finish getBotID()
4. finish getAuth()
5. AND NOW finish the onload function of the getBotID()...

I simply cant get the botID Data  out of the onload function. I already tried to you a callback function but that didnt worked.

Comment: You can't do that.  You should use promises.

Comment: Don't build JSON by hand.  Use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @SLaks do you mean the body variable?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work. Pass an anonymous function to `getBotId` and have it call that back after your first request is finished:

```
function getBotID(domain, callback) {
  var url = "http://" + domain + ":8087/api/v1/botId";
  idRequest.open("GET", url);
  idRequest.onload = callback;
  idRequest.send();
}

function getAuth(domain, user, pass) {
  getBotID(domain, function() {
    var botID = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var url = "http://" + domain + ":8087/api/v1/bot/login";
    body = '{"username": ' + user + ', "password": ' + pass + ', "botId": ' + botID + '}';
    authRequest.open("POST", url);
    authRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    authRequest.onload = function() {
      var authToken = JSON.parse(authRequest.responseText);
    };
    authRequest.send(JSON.stringify(body));
  });
}
```

Comment: I will try this! seems smart didnt think of using the callback like this

Answer (score 0):

So the easiest way is to add an "false" parameter to the getBotIDs idRequest.open() function. This will cause the code to be synchronous and the onload() function will complete before the rest of the code will run down.

Comment: Don't do that; that will completely freeze the browser.

Comment: Hmm I didnt test that so far but Im working with Electron and maybe I can just start up a new window after the "Login Screen".

Comment: No.  You need to learn how to write asynchronous code.  Read http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/